# passing array of struct as a function argument and onlyOwner (web3.py) web3.py

Tags: solidity, blockchain, web3.py, python

hello dear community I wanted to ask why the transaction is not executed correctly.

Code Solidity:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: agpl-3.0
pragma solidity 0.8.9;
contract main{
    struct data{ 
        string data;       
        uint num1;
        uint num2;
        uint num3;
    }

    mapping(string => data[]) public Data;

    address internal owner;

    
    function getOwner() public view returns(address){
        return owner;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner(){
        require(getOwner()==msg.sender, "solo el creado puede modificar.");
        _;
    }
    
    function arrayStructData( data[] memory _data) public{
        for(uint i=0; i<_data.length; i++){ 
            Data[_data[i].data].push(data(_data[i].data,_data[i].num1,_data[i].num2,_data[i].num3));
           
        }
    }
}
```

Code Python:

```
publicKey="0x..."
privateKey= "0x..."
addresscontract= "0x..."
abi="[[...]...]"
contrato= web3.eth.contract(address=addresscontract,abi=abi)
data=[["data",123,321,456],["data2",123,321,456]]
nonce = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(publicKey)
tx= contrato.functions.arrayStructData(data).buildTransaction({
    "from":publicKey,
    "chainId": web3.eth.chain_id,
    "gas": 70000,
    "gasPrice": web3.toWei("40", "gwei"),
    "nonce": nonce,
    })
signed_txn =web3.eth.account.signTransaction(tx, private_key=privateKey)
tx_hash=web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
txid = tx_hash.hex()
print({"Tx Hash":txid})
```

I have tried the combinations with this variable **'data'** in Python:

Num= Decimal(3321)

data= (("node1",Num,Num,Num),("node1",Num,Num,Num))

data= (["node1",3123,3321,3456],["node1",3123,3321,3456])

data= (["node1",Num,Num,Num],["node1",Num,Num,Num])

data= ["node1",Num,Num,Num,"node1",Num,Num,Num]

data= (["node1",str(Num),str(Num),str(Num)],["node1",str(Num),str(Num),str(Num)])

data= (["node1",str(3123),str(3321),str(3456)],["node1",str(3123),str(3321),str(3456)])

---

With these two combinations it is confirmed in the blockchain but **fail** and not append data.

```
data= [["node1",3123,3321,3456],["node1",3123,3321,3456]]
data= [("node1",3123,3321,3456),("node1",3123,3321,3456)]
```

---

Now my question is what am I doing wrong?

How do I organize it so that the transaction is confirmed and it is successful to add to the contract?

How do you pass a struct in Python by parameter so that it processes it correctly in the contract??

Thank you very much for your answers in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Not familiar with web3.py, but have you tried passing them as dicts?

```py
data = [
    {"data": "node1", "num1": 3123, "num2": 3321, "num3": 3456},
    {"data": "node2", "num1": 3123, "num2": 3321, "num3": 3456},
]
```

PS: Cleaned up the names a bit here, since it was confusing (you'd have to change Data.data => Data.identifier above to use this)

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: agpl-3.0
pragma solidity 0.8.9;

contract main{
    struct Data { 
        string identifier;       
        uint num1;
        uint num2;
        uint num3;
    }

    mapping(string => Data[]) public data;

    // ...

    
    function pushData(Data[] calldata _data) public {
        for(uint i=0; i<_data.length; i++){ 
            data[_data[i].identifier].push(_data[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
I added your answer but the contract still fails. with that 'data' variable. in remix it works but in web3.py it fails .

data = [
    {"data": "node1", "num1": 3123, "num2": 3321, "num3": 3456},
    {"data": "node2", "num1": 3123, "num2": 3321, "num3": 3456},
]

Comment: Thank you very much for your collaboration

Answer (score 0):

```
def estimateGas_arrayStructData(data,nonce):
    return web3.eth.estimate_gas(myContract.functions.arrayStructData(data).buildTransaction({
    "from":_publicKey,
    'chainId' : web3.eth.chain_id,
    'nonce' : nonce,
}))


nonce = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(_publicKey)
data = [
{"data": "node1", "num1": 3123, "num2": 3321, "num3": 3456},
{"data": "node2", "num1": 3123, "num2": 3321, "num3": 3456},
]
estimate_gas= estimateGas_arrayStructData(data,nonce)

print("estimate_gas:",estimate_gas)



tx_dict2 = myContract.functions.arrayStructData(data).buildTransaction({
"from":_publicKey,
'chainId' : web3.eth.chain_id,
'gas' : estimate_gas, # 210000
'gasPrice' : web3.eth.gasPrice,
'nonce' : nonce,
})

signed_tx = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(tx_dict2, _privateKey)
tx_hash = web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
tx_receipt = web3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(tx_hash, timeout=120, poll_latency=0.1)
print(tx_receipt)
```

**Everything was the gas estimate.**

In the 'buildTransaction' function I had gas:70000 , insufficient gas

Comment: I am also stuct some similar issue. Is this solved. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/138931/passing-an-array-of-string-from-brownie-python-deployment-script-to-smart-contra